# What options are available for performance tuning a SoundEx query?

Tags: python, django, soundex

I was recently asked about improving website performance for a peers website.

What options are typically used for performance tuning sites enabled with [SoundEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162772/what-is-soundex-and-what-is-it-used-for/77162773#77162773)?

### Overview

Using the homophones Smith/Smythe, I was able to reproduce the behavior of the website query response time described.

These are measured at the browser so there's a lot that could go into the number, but generally speaking the values were what we would expect, less for the non-SoundEx search and more for SoundEx search.

```
Smith  - Not Soundex - (1705 results)  - 6.62s server wait
Smythe - Not Soundex - (8 results).    - 5.51s server wait
Smith  - Soundex     - (4446 results)  - 9.47s server wait
Smythe - Soundex     - (4446 results) - 10.85s server wait
```

### Technical Stack

```
language  - python - 2.7.5
framework - Django - 1.3
database  - not yet known - not yet known
```

> ***NOTE:***
> Database type and version will most likely play a role in what solutions are viable.

### Sources

- [Performance: Put soundex in DB or translate it after the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361760/performance-put-soundex-in-db-or-translate-it-after-the-query)
- https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/Searching-with-Soundex

### Similar Questions

- [Using soundex feature w/django search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590549/using-soundex-feature-w-django-search-engine)